# How should I correctly put some Fragment to FrameLayout in mainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I'm trying to put fragment in MainActivity's `FrameLayout` by clicking the button in MainActivity. It almost works, but the content of MainActivity's `FrameLayout` doesn't get replaced by the Fragment content, but added to it. So the question is: how to make it correct?

My MainActivity class

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.pushMeBtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager f_m = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction f_t = f_m.beginTransaction();

                f_t.replace(R.id.container_layout, new Fragment1()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My activity_main.xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pushMeBtn"
            android:text="push me"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Fragment1 class

```java
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
    }
}
```

My fragment.xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="339dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="fragment1"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hide all content inside layout (or even remove) before adding fragment. It won't remove itself

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko, but what I should do when I going back from fragment to mainActivity? Or, I should make another one fragment, that in MainActivity onCreate method shoud put in FrameLayout, and the from this fragment by click on button, go to another one fragment? (Hope idea is clear)) )

Comment: not clear, but in general to avoid it - just use the clean container for fragments always

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko,But must'n replace method do it all for me?

Comment: the documentation says that it should not. It has nothing to do with the views in container, only replaces the fragment

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko, maybe u can give me some link to example? All examples i found didn't work as I want.